# Check state of 'document.designMode' in JavaScript

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing an add-on to execute a simple javascript that toggles designMode by clicking on a button.
I know it's actually too simple, but there wasn't any add on to do what I'm doing.
But now I want to make it a toggle instead of only setting it to on, by using an IF loop.

Here's my code:

```
var button = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "style-tab",
  label: "Edit Page",
 icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: function(){
    require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
      contentScript: 'document.designMode=\'on\';'
});


}
});
```

I thought I'd make it like this:

```
var button = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "style-tab",
  label: "Edit Page",
 icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: function(){
if (???????? == "off"){
    require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
      contentScript: 'document.designMode=\'on\';'
});
}
else {
   require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
      contentScript: 'document.designMode=\'off\';'
});
}
}
});
```

So what do I need to put at the question marks? I tried alot but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's my add-on, still without toggle:

https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/edit-any-page/

Comment: if (document.designMode == "off"){ ..?

Comment: no that doesn't work, any other solutions?

Comment: That doesn't work because `document` is not accessible from the scope the script is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say on click put in this script:

```
onClick: function(){
    require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
      contentScript: 'document.designMode = document.designMode == "on" ? "off" : "on";'
    });
}
```

Comment: You should add a script on tab change, if the tab is currently in `designMode=on` then you should make sure your button is in depressed state.